# Using HERE URL scheme doesn't allow tapping the Start button

Tags: ios, objective-c, here-api

We are using the `HERE` URL Scheme to pass coordinates. E.g. `here-place://{lat},{lng}`

```
NSString *mapDirHere = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"here-route://%1.6f,%1.6f,%@/%1.6f,%1.6f,%@", latitude, longitude, NSLocalizedString(@"Current Location", nil), self.selectedCoordinate.latitude, self.selectedCoordinate.longitude, self.titleName] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:mapDirHere]];
```

[image]

This does open `HERE` with the correct route, but the "Start" button is never activated, so our users can't start the route.

Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: Where is start button? and how is it related to this URL.

Comment: @prabodhprakash That URL is the URL scheme I use to open `HERE` maps and send the coordinates.

Comment: Do you also control this Start button or is provided by some framework etc? If you control, please could you provide that part of code?

Comment: @prabodhprakash I don't control it. As I mentioned, this is integrated with the `HERE` app.

Answer (score 0):

The HERE iOS SDK comes with an example for starting and stopping navigation as you would like to implement in your use case.

https://github.com/heremaps/here-ios-sdk-examples/tree/master/turn-by-turn-navigation-ios-swift

All examples are updated with every update of the SDK so check them out at:
https://github.com/heremaps/here-ios-sdk-examples

Comment: The question was not about the Here SDK but about deep-linking to the Here WeGo app. Is this documented somewhere?